# How to find previous month's last day for last year in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to find out the previous month's last day, but I want it for last year, in Teradata SQL.

Examples:

If current date is '2022-02-02', then the output I require is '2021-01-31'
If current date is '2022-07-25', then the output I require is '2021-06-30'

Comment: If you add some code , it could help us answer your question faster. Like what statements you tried ...

Comment: SELECT ADD_MONTHS(Current_Date – EXTRACT(DAY FROM Current_DATE))
This is what I use for extracting previous month's last date for this year. A little confused for extracting the same for last year

Comment: I don't see how your answer wont work for last year. The only thing unstable is February's last day and jumping between January to December of last year witch is covered in your answer .

Answer (score 0):

Substract 13 months from today and then find the last day of this month:

```
last_day(add_months(current_date, -13)
```